# Можно ли удалить только выбранные поля из строки MySQL

Tags: mysql

Можно ли как то удалить значение выбранного столбца из строки MySQL. Допустим есть таблица users и в нем поля id, username, regdate, image. Из них например можно было удалить (или обнулить чтоли) только значение поля regdate например а остальные пусть оставались. Вообще возможно ли такое ? Или кроме DELETE есть ещё и другая команда для таких целей ? Буду благодарен за Ваши ответы !

Comment: попробуйте команду UPDATE )

Comment: Спасибо,  Dmitry OnGamer. Но у меня такая ситуация что UPDATE просто не поможет ) Дело в том что при заполнении формы пользователь сначала вводит одни данные и нажимает на далее (где скрипт выполняет запрос добавления этих данных в базу и редирект на вторую страницу) на второй странице есть ещё форма где некоторые инпуты заполняються из  той же таблицы что заполнено на первой странице. Вот такое вот извращение своего рода ) Остальные поля этой формы заполняются из другого файла но тот файл тоже берет инфу из той таблицы

Comment: DELETE удаляет ЗАПИСЬ. А не поле. Удаление поля возможно только из всей таблицы, а не из одной записи. А вот удалить (но правильный при этом термин - изменить значение на "пустое") - возможно для ЗНАЧЕНИЯ одного поля одной записи. @DmitryOnGamer указал, как именно.

Comment: @AlexStassov А при чём тут описанное "удаление"? ему места в Вашей технологии как-то не видать.

Comment: Akina, да наверное я что то не понял. В любом случае спасибо за ответы , друзья!) пойду наверное другим путем как это ни странно сделаю отдельную таблицу )

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо делать **UPDATE** только regdate значения:

```
UPDATE `USERS` SET `REGDATE` = '<{NEW_DATE}>' WHERE `ID` = <{ID}>;
```

Вместо **<{NEW_DATE}>** и **<{ID}>** вставите нужного Вам значения.